# Use joypad instead of mouse for aiming in Xonotic

Tags: games, gamepad

Is it possible to use joypad instead of mouse in Xonotic?

According to this setting it looks that not.

I need especially the keys for aiming, which I can't find under key bindings.
[image]

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @heynnema Ubuntu 18.04.3

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/156017/gamepad-setup-ignored-by-games and https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/joystick-connection-request-for-xonotic/6244 and Google "Xonotic joystick input" for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are utilities to map inputs to other devices. One of them is qjoypad: http://qjoypad.sourceforge.net/

Discussed xboxdrv in another thread:[How can a gamepad control THE mouse?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114895/how-can-a-gamepad-control-the-mouse)

You can write a simple code run it background in python or C using a library. You need to look an inputmapper library for python or c for linux.

Or you can write mouse driver which get its input from joypad: https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2476

Comment: I tried to compile qjoypad, but it ends with error message "Makefile:159: recipe for target 'qjoypad' failed"

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/239176/alternative-to-qjoypad

Folks discuss how to get it running and there is also joy2key...

Keep trying you will get one of them working ...

You can always mail to the guy who write the software and ask him ...

Comment: GURSU I installed it with apt-get package manager